# How to change "keyboard language text input" when I change language in my app

Tags: android, configuration, localization, resources

I wanna create an app, and in my app support many language. But I can't change keyboard language when i change the language.
Here is the code to change language in my app...

> `String [] lCode = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language_code);`
>   `Locale locale = new Locale(lCode[position]);`
>   `Locale.setDefault(locale);`
>   `Configuration config = new Configuration();`
>   `config.locale = locale;`
>   `getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());`

and here the language_code values xml...

> en-us zh_TW fr de ru es